# How can I add default breadcrumbs to cms Page?

Tags: magento2, cms, breadcrumbs

I want to add to my home page (Cms) the breadcrumbs on top, I have allready enabled it in the admin area and also added it in the layout file like so:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

[image]

This is fine but when I visit for example a category page the breadcrumbs is all messed up:

[image: dd]

I know that the layout I added is a custom one so that's why I see Home in front page but I am not sure how to fix it.

**EDITED**

I found a way to make this work, basicly I change the way the breadcrumbs is called in the layout file, I changed it to :

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/breadcrumbs.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

This did the fix for me, but if anyone know how to add the breadcrumbs in another way it would help me aswell, thanks